# $I$-adic completion

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, noetherian

> Let $A$ be a commutative noetherian ring, and suppose that $A$ is $I$-adically complete with respect to some ideal $I\subseteq A$. Is it true that for any ideal $J\subseteq I$, the ring $A$ is also $J$-adically complete?

Edit. Recall that a ring $A$ is $I$-adically complete if the canonical morphism $A\to \varprojlim A/I^n$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Can you expand on the definition of $I$-adically complete? I'm not sure if $\bigcap_nI^n=0$ is necessary, which would make a difference to the counterexample, if any.

Comment: @George: Dear George, Usually $I$-adically complete is taken to mean "complete and separated", i.e. that the intersection you ask about *does* equal $0$.

Comment: This result is true in a more general situation, see [090T](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/090T).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is "yes".

Since $A$ is Noetherian, for any $m$ the finitely generated $A$-module
$A/J^m$ is $I$-adically complete, and so $A/J^m$ is the inverse limit over $n$
of $A/(I^n + J^m)$.   Now $J^m \subset I^m,$ and so $I^n \subset I^n + J^m
\subset I^m$ when $n \geq m$.  Thus the inverse limit (over $m$) of $A/J^m$ is
the same as the inverse limit (over $n$) of $A/I^n$, and we see that $A$ is $J$-adically complete.

Another way to think about it is that $A$ is $I$-adically complete (and separated, which is part of the requirement of "complete") if and only if any $I$-adic Cauchy sequence of elements of $A$ has a unique $I$-adic limit.  Since a $J$-adic Cauchy sequence is also an $I$-adic sequence, a $J$-adic Cauchy $(a_n)$ sequence also has a unique $I$-adic limit, say $a$.

Now if we choose $n_0$ so that $a_m - a_n \in J^k$ if $m,n \geq n_0$,
then we see that $a - a_m = a - a_{n} + a_{n} - a_m \in J^k + I^l,$ where 
$l$ can be made arbitrarily large by choosing $n$ large enough (since $a_n$
converges to $a$ in the $I$-adic topology).  Thus $a - a_m \in \cap_l J^k + I^l.$  This intersection is equal to $J^k$ (by $I$-adic completeness of $A/J^k$)
and so $a-a_m \in J^k$.  Thus in fact $(a_n)$ converges to $a$ in the $J$-adic topology, and so $A$ is $J$-adically complete.

Comment: Matt: can you expand on that?

Comment: @Matt: The bit I found tricky when thinking about this is showing that $A/J^m$ is $I$-adically complete. Why is that? Does it follow from being finitely generated?

Comment: Actually, it does not follow. I have a counterexample in mind.

Comment: I'm not sure that the ring in my counterexample is noetherian. Do you have a reference or proof that $A/J^m$ is $I$-adically complete?

Comment: @George: Dear George, The Artin--Rees lemma implies that any f.g. module of an $I$-adically complete Noetherian ring is itself $I$-adically complete.  Regards,

Comment: @Matt: I see it now. That works, thanks. I suppose a link to a proof of completeness for fg modules or a brief argument why this is true would have been nice.

Comment: @George: Dear George, It's a pretty standard fact, and a statement and proof can be found in Matsumura, and presumably any other text that discusses completions.  One statement of this result is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completion_(ring_theory)  (See property 3 in the list of properties, which implies that if $R$ --- in the notation of the article --- is Noetherian and $I$-adically complete, then so is any f.g. $R$-module.)

Comment: @Matt: Ah, yes, it clearly follows immediately from property 3 of the linked WP page. Thanks.

Comment: @MattE: Can you explain why the inverse limit over m of A/J^m is the same as the inverse limit of A/I^n?