# If $R$ is $I$ and $J$-adically complete, then it is $(I+J)$-adically complete.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring with ideals $I$ and $J$.  I already proved the following:

> Lemma: If $I \subseteq J$ and $R$ is $J$-adically complete, then $R$ is $I$-adically complete.

And now I'm trying to prove:

> If $R$ is $I$ and $J$-adically complete, then $R$ is $(I+J)$-adically complete.

By the lemma, it's easy to reduce to the case where $I$ and $J$ are principal ideals (Edit: not really; I can just reduce to the case where one of them is principal.  Anyway here is what I did assuming both are principal).  Let's say $I = (a)$ and $J = (b)$.  Since $\bigcap\limits_n I^n$ and $\bigcap\limits_n J^n$ are $0$, it is straightforward to check that $\bigcap\limits_n (I+J)^n = 0$ as well.  Now let $x_n \in R$ be a Cauchy sequence with respect to $(a,b)$.  I am vaguely aware of a result that you can realize that $(a,b)$-adic completion of $R$ as the quotient of the power series ring $$R[[X,Y]]/(X-a,Y-b)$$ Since $R$ is separated with respect to $(a,b)$, the natural map $R \rightarrow \hat{R}$ is injective.  To show that $R$ is $(a,b)$-adically complete, we need to show that this map is surjective.  Informally, I can write an element in $\hat{R}$ as $$\sum\limits_{n,m \geq 0} c_{nm} a^n b^m = \sum\limits_n [\sum\limits_m c_{nm} b^m]a^n $$ and since $\hat{R}$ is $(b)$-adically complete, each sum $\sum\limits_m c_{nm} b^m$ is 'really' an element of $R$.  Then $\hat{R}$ is also $(a)$-adically complete, so the entire sum is 'really' an element of $R$.

I think there is a lot of formal justification missing from my argument.  Intuitively it makes sense to me, but I am not sure whether what I wrote down is salvageable as a proof, or whether it is even correct.  What do you think?

Comment: How exactly are you reducing to the case that $I$ and $J$ are principal?

Comment: I don't actually seem to be able to do that, thank you.  I can only reduce to the case where one of them is principal.

Comment: There seems to be a proof in http://users.math.msu.edu/users/rotthaus/teaching/math911/ (solutions to homework 8, (2)(b)).

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17685/i-adic-completion