# $R$ be Noetherian ring. Let $I \subseteq J$ be proper ideals of $R$. If $R$ is $J$-adically complete, then is $R$ complete $I$-adically?

Tags: commutative-algebra, noetherian, topological-rings, filtered-modules

Let $R$ be Noetherian ring. Let $I \subseteq J$ be proper ideals of $R$. If $R$ is $J$-adically complete, then is $R$ complete $I$-adically ?

I was proceeding as follows: Let $\{x_n\}$ be an $I$-adic Cauchy sequence in $R$ ; to show $\{x_n\}$ converges $I$-adically in $R$ . Now for every $I^k$, there is some $n_0$ such that $x_{n+1}-x_n \in I^k,\forall n \ge n_0$. Then $x_{n+1}-x_n \in J^k,\forall n \ge n_0$, so $\{x_n\}$ is $J$-adic Cauchy in $ R$, so converges $J$-adically to some $x\in R$ i.e. for every $k \ge 1$, $\exists n_k\ge 1$ such that $x_n-x \in J^k,\forall n \ge n_k$. Then I am stuck. I don't know if it can be done considering the algebraic definition of completion or not.

Please help.

Comment: Why $x_{n+1}-x_n\in I_k$ is that the definition of $I$-adic Cauchy sequence?

Comment: @dcheuk: Yes ... $I$-adic topology is the linear topology on $R$ with a neighborhood basis at $0 \in R$ given by $\{I^k\}_{k\ge 1}$

Comment: $x_{n+1}-x_n=x_{n+1}-x_{n_k}+x_{n_k}-x{n}\in I^k+J^k$

Comment: @dcheuk: Sorry but I didn't get what you are trying to say ...

Comment: I think this is false in general: take $R:=K[X]\times K$, $K$ a field, $J:=K[X]$, $I:=(X)$.

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard : It is not ... I found a proof here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17685/i-adic-completion

Comment: @users - You're right. I used the definition which does *not* requires that $R$ be separated. The definition which requires separation is apparently more standard. I didn't know. Anyway, the strong definition is the one you're using. Nice question!

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard: I don't think I am using $R$ is separated ...

Comment: @users - Then, what's wrong with my potential counterexample? (The proof in your link does use separation, right?)

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard: No ... the proof in the link does not use separation ... and about your example , I am not sure what the $I$ and $J$-adic completions of $R$ are ...

Comment: @users - In the answer you link to I noticed the phrase "$A$ is $I$-adically complete (and separated, which is part of the requirement of "complete")". - In my example, $R$ is $J$-adically complete and its $J$-adic separated completion is $K$. The $I$-adic separated completion is $K[[X]]\times K$.

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard: actually $I$-adically complete automatically implies separated ... the kernel of the natural map $\psi : R \to \hat R$ is $\cap_{n\ge 1} I^n$ , and $R$ is complete iff  $\psi$ is an isomorphism ... it might be possible that the topological definition of completion is equivalent to this under the assumption of separatedness ... then you might be right ..

Comment: @users - I was using the naive definition "any Cauchy sequence has at least one limit", but I think that **you** are right in the sense that you're using the much more sensible definition. Again, I like your question very much! +1

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard: thank you very much ... I will let you know after going through the definitions whether the algebraic and topological definitions match without separated ...

Comment: @users - Don't the last two paragraphs of https://math.stackexchange.com/a/17710/660 solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence $(x_n)$, being $I$-adically Cauchy by assumption, tends $I$-adically, and thus $J$-adically, to $y$ for some $y$ in $R$. This implies $y=x$.

**Edit 1.** I used [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/17710/660) of Matt E.

**EDIT 2.** We can also repeat Matt E's nice argument:

In the setting of the question, let $p$ be a positive integer, let $q\in\mathbb N$ be such that $r\ge q$ implies $x_r-x_{r+1}\in I^p$. It suffices to show $x_r-x\in I^p$.

Let's forget the $I$-adic topology, and work only with the $J$-adic topology.

Set $u_n:=x_r-x_{r+n}$. Then $(u_n)$ is a sequence in $I^p$ converging to $x_r-x$. As $I^p$ is closed, we have $x_r-x\in I^p$, as desired.